# java parseInt using output

Tags: java, parseint

The code below takes user input of 10 integers, uses `String.split(" ")` on the space, parses them as integers and prints them out.

```
public class variableGrowth
{
    public main variableGrowth()
    {
        System.out.print('\u000c');
            //scanner and variables 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputInt = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("These are the integers you entered: "+inputInt);

        String[] items = inputInt.split(" ");
        int[] results = new int[items.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            try {
                int stuff = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
                System.out.println(stuff);
                } 
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.println(results);
                System.out.println(errorMessage);   
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

For each iteration of the loop, can the output be accessed so I could complete a sum in the loop and print it out? For example:

```
System.out.print(stuff(firstInt));  -- the first integer entered, 
result= current + (current * (firstInt/ 100)); // or anything like this
System.out.print("something meaningful: "+result);
```

Comment: how about Arrays.stream(items).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum(); ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile unless you declare the variable errorMessage.

You just initialize an array to store your results but you never use it. In your loop, you should store each parsed value.

```
results[i] = stuff;
```

Then outside your loop you can access all your integers to do some stuff.

But for a simple sum operation, you can define a variable then sum each new int inside the loop.

```
int sum;
for ...
    // get your stuff here
    sum += stuff;
```

Also I did not notice your method signature at first. But the signature of a main method is

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

In Java, your method signature should follow :

```
[accessor] [static] 'returnType' yourMethodName('yourParams')
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create an additional variable which will contain your running total.

```
int total = 0;
for (...) {
    System.out.println(value);
    total += value;
    System.out.println("Running Total: " + total)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this. If you are looking for a direct sum of all the numbers, just keep a sum variable outside of the loop and keep a working sum through all iterations.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  try {
    int stuff = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
    sum += stuff;
    ...
}
```

Another way is to store all of the numbers (especially if you need to perform other operations with them) in a list or an array and perform your operations after the fact.

```
int[] numbers = new int[items.length];
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  try {
    int stuff = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
    numbers[i] = stuff;
    ...
}

// Perform operations here
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think the second part is exactly what I'm looking for. When I put: double c = numbers[i]/100; Right after your code, then System.out.println(c); , c always equals zero. any thoughts?

Comment: I'm assuming you're putting that line (double c = numbers[i] / 100) inside the for loop? (The i variable doesn't exist outside the for loop). Are your numbers too small? If numbers[i] is < 100, you will get 0 because you are doing integer division. You likely want to divide by 100.0 or divide by (double)100

Answer (score 0):

Go with streams (Java 8):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print('\u000c');
        //scanner and variables
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputInt = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("These are the integers you entered: "+inputInt);

        String[] items = inputInt.split(" ");

        int sum = Arrays.stream(items)
                .mapToInt(x -> Integer.parseInt(x))
                .sum();

        System.out.println(String.format("Sum is: %s", sum));
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I call each element individually? to clarify again, i'm not looking for a sum of the integers in the array, I want to do a sum with each integer of the array as a variable. ie. at loop iteration 0, i want to do something like result[0] * 3. at loop iteration 1, i want to do result [1] * 3 then print all results.